# Overflow error when assigning input value to range vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is something really simple but I have reviewed all the suggested questions on stack overflow as well as searched other vba forums and I can't for the life of me find anything that's working.  My code is short so I've included the whole thing.  I just want to assign the input value entered into AcctNum to every cell in the range A2:ALastRow but I get an overflow error at the assignment line (marked below).

```
Sub PrepBogsOrderDetail()

    Dim AcctNum As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Double

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    AcctNum = InputBox("Please enter the SoldTo number")

    Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("A1").Value = "Account Number"

    *'Overflow error happens at this line*
    Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = AcctNum

End Sub
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not a *stack* overflow. What does the error message say? Also, I can't reproduce the problem. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Changing `LastRow` from `Double` to `Long` might help. It would make more sense anyway since a row number is not a floating point value. What is the value of `LastRow` when the error appears?

Comment: what's the `AcctNum` value when you hit the error?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the stack mistake @JohnColeman.  I get "Run-time error '6': Overflow."  Odd that it works for you.

Comment: Changing `LastRow` from `Double` to `Long` solved the issue.